# LLVM IRBuilder::CreateGlobalStringPtr Segmentation Fault

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm facing an issue where `IRBuilder<>::CreateGlobalStringPtr` causes a segmentation fault on Ubuntu Trusty using the development branch of LLVM. I do not get a segfault on my mac book or when using older LLVM Versions (4, 5, or 6).

I created a little [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MichaReiser/a15a9af8856d17d2456f02795f80d6f1) that reproduces the issue.

I also tried to analyze the issue myself and found out, that `CreateGlobalString` works just fine. So the issue seems to be related to the following call to `CreateInBoundsGEP`.

Is something wrong with my setup code or might this be an issue with LLVM itself (even though the mentioned methods haven't been touched for years).

Thanks,
Micha

Comment: I've tried your snippet with 3.7 and the current RC (6.0.0) and it works fine. It's not unheard of to be an issue with LLVM trunk as is at the moment. Perhaps, you could augment your question with a backtrace (`bt full` in GDB).